# Ember.js data records shows content: null in relationships inspector

Tags: node.js, express, ember.js

I have the following code in my 'user.js' model in ember-data:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  organization: DS.belongsTo('organization'),
  //other stuff
});
```

The CRUD for the website is working as expected, and in MongoDB I can see the following for the organization field of User:

```
"organization" : ObjectId("571974742ce868d575b79d6a"),
```

BUT, and I'm not sure if this is an error in my code or me not understanding how Ember-data works, I cannot access that ID from a model hook like so:

```
model(){
        return this.store.findRecord("user", this.get("session.currentUser.id"))
            .then(user => this.store.findRecord("location", {organization: user.organization}));
    }
```

And if I go to the Ember inspector to observe the belongsTo attribute of the User object, I see:

```
organization: <(subclass of Ember.ObjectProxy):ember956>
```

But clicking through I see `content: null`

What am I doing wrong? Could it be a server-side error?

**Edit** including JSON response from server for the above findRecord("user") call:

```
{
   "links":{
      "self":"/users/5719749a2ce868d575b79d6b"
   },
   "included":[
      {
         "type":"organizations",
         "id":"571974742ce868d575b79d6a",
         "links":{
            "self":"/organizations/571974742ce868d575b79d6a"
         },
         "attributes":{
            "creation-date":"2016-04-22T00:46:44.779Z"
         }
      }
   ],
   "jsonapi":{
      "version":"1.0"
   },
   "data":{
      "type":"users",
      "id":"5719749a2ce868d575b79d6b",
      "links":{
         "self":"/users/5719749a2ce868d575b79d6b"
      },
      "attributes":{
         "email":"danthwa@gmail.com",
         "first-name":"Daniel",
         "last-name":"Thompson",
         "registration-date":"2016-04-22T00:47:22.534Z"
      },
      "relationships":{
         "organization":{
            "type":"organizations",
            "id":"571974742ce868d575b79d6a"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: ObjectProxy is a potentially unresolved object, is your organization supposed to be asynchronous?

Comment: i.e. does your server's json payload for the user contain organization information as well, or does it contain just an identifier for the organization?

Comment: It contains a relationships key:  "relationships":{"organization":{"type":"organizations","id":"571974742ce868d575b79d6a"}}. So I suppose that's just an identifier? All I need to do is be able to access that id I think, since I am trying to populate a model based on links TO that organization from different schemas.

Comment: @Kingpin2k I added the JSON response payload for findRecord user call up there. Also, I am noticing that if I am to console log user I can access the ID but not other fields, so: (user => console.log(user.email)) returns a computed property object without any of the information I'm thinking I would see.

Comment: I'm not pro at the jsonapi spec or how it's implemented in Ember Data (personally I think the spec is bloated garbage).  Here's a jsbin we can work with:  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vodutiteku/edit?html,js,output

Comment: From what it looks like to me, it looks like the relationships isn't being built up correctly, I think the type and id inside of organization need to be within a data object (see the jsbin)

Comment: Your efforts here are much appreciated Kingpin! I am going to append that data object back into the response with normalizeResponse and see if that fixes the issue. If it doesn't, I will adapt the site from a json api spec back to REST, as I think that's really what Ember data is optimized for? This middleware framework (jsonapify) didn't like seeing the data attribute, so  currently there's a serializer that removes it in the request. Didn't occur to me to append it back in on the response. D'oh!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed. As stated by Kingpin2k,

> the relationships isn't being built up correctly, I think the type and id inside of organization need to be within a data object.

This applies to Ember sites expecting a [JSON API spec](http://jsonapi.org/) payload, meaning they have been configured to use [JSONAPISerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html) for incoming payloads.